# Multiple INSERT INTO with single RETURNING?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm wondering if it's possible to selectively `RETURNING` single row when, in fact, there are multiple `INSERT INTO` statements.

Here is my current query:

```
WITH ins AS
  (INSERT INTO Chats DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING chat_id)
INSERT INTO Users_Chats (user_id, chat_id)
  SELECT user_id, i.chat_id
  FROM unnest(ARRAY[$1, $2]) user_id
       CROSS JOIN
       ins i
RETURNING i.chat_id;
```

To give it a little context, it receives two `user_id`s who join together a **single** chat and returns a **single** shared `chat_id`.

Currently it returns two rows with single `chat_id` column with the same value.

Although, I can simply ignore the second row, I'm curious as to a way to limit to single row? Supposedly by only `RETURNING` for the first `INSERT INTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
WITH ins1 AS (
      INSERT INTO Chats DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING chat_id
     ),
     ins2 as (
      INSERT INTO Users_Chats (user_id, chat_id)
          SELECT user_id, i.chat_id
          FROM unnest(ARRAY[$1, $2]) user_id CROSS JOIN
               ins1 i
    )
select min(chat_id)
from ins2;
```

That is, you can chain the CTEs with `insert`, and then process the final result however you like.